# Windows 10 desktop no longer booting after hard disk swap

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot

I have a work desktop, a Dell Vostro, which initially worked fine except for long periods of freezing after being awoken from sleep.

I consulted and was told it was a hard disk issue. I received a used 2.5" hard disk which I replaced the problematic 3.5" hard drive with, formatted and installed Windows 10 20H2, which I then downgraded to 1909 via a clean install bearing sudden blackouts and starting over multiple times.

I then transferred the old files from the 3.5" hard disk by swapping the 2.5" hard disk and copying it to a shared folder.

Upon removing the 3.5" and reinserting the 2.5", the machine could no longer boot, just a black screen, no Dell logo is seen, nothing. The fans are running though.

I have tried swapping it on a number of computers, disk checks on other computers, repairing the drives and nothing has worked. The 3.5" also no longer works and similarly can't be booted from. I am at a loss here.

Edit: I formatted my 2.5" and want to install Windows on it but I am unable to boot from my bootable drive (black screen). I want to boot from the 3.5".

Comment: If there were multiple problems when installing on the new disk, then the problem is not with the disk. This computer may need professional repairs.

Answer (score 1):

If the Dell logo doesn't even show that indicates there is definitely a Hardware issue since the BIOS itself isn't loading up. BIOS always starts up before a hard drive is mounted and before it checks if there was an OS on the hard drive.  You should go to a repair shop since it might be a power, ram or any other issue.

Comment: *BIOS always starts up before a hard drive is mounted*... Indeed. However, faulty HDDs, SSDs or even ODDs can and often prevents access to BIOS/UEFI settings and stop the normal boot process.

Comment: @ChanganAuto True, but my point still stands though "definitely a Hardware issue since the BIOS itself isn't loading up"